# Error using TinyMCE component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'm new in Agular 2 and I'm trying to use the TinyMCE editor on my project.

I followed this instructions in order to create and use the tinyMCE component: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/

After following the steps, I can't make TinyMCE work, I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'elementId' since it isn't a known property of 'simple-tiny'.
>
> 1. If 'simple-tiny' is an Angular component and it has 'elementId' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'simple-tiny' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

This is my code:

**tiny-editor.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, 
Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import 'tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/modern';

declare var tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-tiny',
  template: `<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`
})
export class TinyEditorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: string;
  @Output() onEditorContentChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

  editor;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: `#${this.elementId}`,
      skin_url: '../assets/skins/lightgray',
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup change', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorContentChange.emit(content);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<simple-tiny [elementId]="'descripcion'" (onEditorContentChange)="keyupHandler($event)"></simple-tiny>
```

I already imported the component to the **app.module.ts**.
I already added the scripts to the **angular-cli.json**.

I'm using TinyMCE version 4.5.6

What am I missing?

Here's my app.module.ts. I'm using a template.
**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tabs';
import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';

import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import { AsideToggleDirective } from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './shared/breadcrumb.component';

// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

//Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { SimpleLayoutComponent } from './layouts/simple-layout.component';

//Modules
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

//Services
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { PropertiesService } from './services/properties.service';
import { TypesService } from './services/types.service';

import { TinyEditorComponent } from './tiny-editor/tiny-editor.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    AuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    SimpleLayoutComponent,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
    AsideToggleDirective,
    TinyEditorComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    PropertiesService,
    TypesService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Not sure about the builder question, could it be angular-cli?

Comment: What builder are you using to build the app ?

Comment: Share your `app.module.ts`

Comment: @yurzui I've added the app.module.ts

Comment: @elpddev the builder is angular-cli I think.

Answer (score 0):

The elementId refers to the HTML element you want to wrap to the editor, and is received in the Directive as an @Input parameter. Try just using:

```
selector: '#' + this.elementId,
```

It would be

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      skin_url: '../assets/skins/lightgray',
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup change', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorContentChange.emit(content);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

If this still not works, please try using a default select identifier, i.e.

```
select: '#wysiwygEditor',
```

And in the HTML

```
<simple-tiny id="wysiwygEditor" (onEditorContentChange)="keyupHandler($event)"></simple-tiny>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.